# Getting values out of a NIB with initWithCoder: for subclasses of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I created a subclass of `UIView`, added an `UIView` to a nib and changed the class name to my class.

Now, I need the original size and position of the view from the nib. A look in the .xib file reveals the required information within the key `NSFrame`:

```
<object class="IBUIView" id="79599448">
  <reference key="NSNextResponder" ref="972514174"/>
  <int key="NSvFlags">292</int>
  <string key="NSFrame">{{76, 62}, {224, 44}}</string>
  <reference key="NSSuperview" ref="972514174"/>
  <reference key="NSNextKeyView" ref="621711566"/>  
  <reference key="IBUIBackgroundColor" ref="1064304267"/>
  <string key="targetRuntimeIdentifier">IBCocoaTouchFramework</string>
</object>
```

How can I extract this key in `initWithCoder:`?

Comment: not sure if i follow your question, but if you are trying to get a UIViews frame (its position and size)... self.frame will work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question, but once the XIB is initialized, you can grab the position and size of a UIView with

```
NSRect originalFrame = myView.frame;
```

As long as you put this code somewhere where it will be run just after the XIB initializes, this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am subclassing UIPickerView to create a horizontal one. In order to rotate/transform correctly I need the original designated coordinates before UIPickerView changes its height